# Why OData impletation uses $skip + $top instead of $skip + $take?

Tags: odata

Based on Linq, EF and hibernate **$skip** and **$take** seems to be more readable and understandable than **$skip** and **$top**.

Is there some special reasoning to decide for $top?

> 5.1.5 System Query Options $top and $skip
>
> The $top system query option requests the number of items in the queried collection to be included in the result. The $skip query option requests the number of items in the queried collection that are to be skipped and not included in the result. A client can request a particular page of items by combining $top and $skip.
>
> The semantics of $top and $skip are covered in the [OData-Protocol] document. The [OData-ABNF] top and skip syntax rules define the formal grammar of the $top and $skip query options respectively.

[OData Documentation...](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc395267182)

Comment: Since I do not meet your criteria of someone who participated in OData implementation discussion, I'll state my **guess** as a comment - OData started as something called "ADO.Net Data Services".. i.e. it was initially conceived as a service to expose data from SQL *like* sources.. Since SQL has `top`, I would **guess** they chose to use `$top` as well.